# Disable Native Lazy Load Images in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, image, google-chrome, lazy-loading, native

It seems on my Android tablet, that chrome has implemented a native feature, that lazy load images only if there are near the viewport. 
I already had implemented loading images via `srcset` and `js`. This worked always fantastic on every Browser including Chrome on Desktop. Reviewing my page in Chrome 71.0.3578.99 leads to a fundamental jumpy experience with delays.

Can I disable the feature somehow (e.g. MetaTag or attribute)? Do someone know a place where start to read about this? Can't find documentation.

Comment: Seems there is a lack of information from Google, but there is an article https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/built-in-lazy-loading-lands-in-google-chrome-canary/ that refers to `Feature-Policy` header proposal: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-feature-policy/issues/193. It looks like this header is supported in latest Chromium sources, but I'm not sure it correctly supports lazy loading on/off (`Feature-Policy` is related to a set of other options as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can enable/disable lazy loading in dedicated interface accessible within the browser. Type `chrome://flags` and search for `disable-lazy-image-loading` and `disable-lazy-frame-loading`. For all accessible settings, type: `chrome://chrome-urls`.